# NoClassDefFoundError ClassNotFoundException errors in Google Play Console since sdk's update

Tags: android, admob, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror, android-9.0-pie

My wapp was being compiled and targeting api 27 and using a previous version of firebase ads. Now, after updating the app and compiling and targeting api 28 and using the last version of each sdk, including firebase ads (which is the same as admob), also compiling with R8 instead of proguard, I'm getting a lot of exceptions like this in the google play console Crashes section:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at gk.b (gk.java:3)
  at gl.a (gl.java:3)
  at gn.a (gn.java:18)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a (ar.java:5)
  at fo.a (fo.java:19)
  at fo.run (fo.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at ab.loadClass (ab.java:4)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at gk.b (gk.java:3)
  at gl.a (gl.java:3)
  at gn.a (gn.java:18)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a (ar.java:5)
  at fo.a (fo.java:19)
  at fo.run (fo.java:8)
```

I don't know why it's obfuscated, because I uploaded the mapping file, maybe it is because the newer android studio version uses R8 instead of proguard.

Some users are putting bad reviews because they see the crashes since app update. I can't get the app crash in any of my devices.

The crashes are reported on Xiaomi MI 8 and OnePlus 5T devices, but for sure must be more.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to disable both `minifyEnabled` (code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization) and `shrinkResources` fields in your **build.gardle** configuration.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I think it's happening due to minifyEnabled code shrinking which rename names of classes.

Since removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on, you have to disable shrinkResources too.

[See android documentation on shrink-code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)